# please help parse json to model using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have `json` out put like this

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "battery": "AHAJAJ1DH13T0021",
    "data": {
        "id": 6,
        "userId": 3,
        "shopId": 1,
        "transactionStatus": "PENDING",
        "expiredAt": "2019-01-04T03:01:18.878Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-01-04T02:01:18.916Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-04T02:01:18.916Z",
        "paymentId": null,
        "batteryNo": null
    }
}
```

and this is my model class

```
public class BookBattery implements Serializable {

private int id;
private String ebikeSn;
private String bookTime;
private String batterySn;
private String transactionStatus;
private String paymentId;
private String batteryNo;
private String addressBook;
private int leftSeconds;
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class BookBatteryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<BookBattery> mBookBatteryList = new ArrayList<>();

public BookBatteryListAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public void setList(List<BookBattery> bookBatteryList) {
    mBookBatteryList.clear();
    mBookBatteryList.addAll(bookBatteryList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear() {
    mBookBatteryList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_book_battery, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(inflate);
}
```

......

and already generate setter and getter, i wanna ask how to parse json from server to my class then i can display into display result inside recyclerview????

Comment: You need 2 model classes to parse this result. First one will be for your root json object and second one for your data json object

Comment: no i just make 1 model class for all value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can parse your `JSON` like this for e.g.

```
JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject dataObj = responseObj.getJSONObject("data");
```

And here then you go by parsing fields inside data object like.

```
int id = dataObj.getInt("id");
String transactionStatus = dataObj.getString("transactionStatus");
```

Likewise you can do for all fields.

And then setup data to you `Model Class Object`.

```
BookBattery bookBattery = new BookBattery();
bookBattery.setId(id);
```

Likewise you can set data for all and add it to the `List<BookBattery>` and setup that to `RecyclerView Adapter`.